# Declaring React Native routes in child components not working

Tags: reactjs, react-native, routes, nested, react-router

I'm having trouble implementing nested routes within react native using react router v4.

If the nested route is declared in App.js it works fine, however when it is declared within another component, redirecting doesn't work.

I was trying to follow the documentation here: `https://reacttraining.com/react-router/core/guides/philosophy/nested-routes`

Is it something simple?

I've created a simple repo which has all the code to replicate:

1. `git clone https://github.com/814k31/TestReactNativeRoutingv4.git`
2. `cd TestReactNativeRoutingv4`
3. `npm install`
4. `npm run <platform>`

https://github.com/814k31/TestReactNativeRoutingv4

Comment: Updated repo to also include a reactjs example with the same problem
new repo name https://github.com/814k31/TestReactNestedRoutingv4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the react guys on concord

I needed to use relative links otherwise the router would look for a route within the root component (App.js) and wouldn't know about the nested route.

`` const Tacos  = ({ match }) => (
    // here's a nested div
    <div>
        <Route exact
            path={`${match.url}/Carnitas`} // The "match.url" is critical here
            component={Carnitas}
        />
        TACOS
        <Redirect to={`${match.url}/Carnitas`} push /> // And here
    </div>
) ``